# Firebase RecycleView Adapter not updating even after notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have registered a listener for a specific firebase database reference. Once the data is "changed" it displays a toast message and should add the chatMessage to the list and show the item in the recycle view.  However, only the toast message is displayed, but the item isn't added to the recycle view.  I believe it is caused by an issue with the RecycleView Adapter, but I am unable to pinpoint the location.

```
public void getMessageByMessageUUID(final MessageAdapter messageAdapter, final String chatUUID, final String messageUUID) {
    MESSAGE_REFERENCE.child(chatUUID).child(messageUUID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ChatMessage message = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Welcome " + chatUUID + " " + message.getMessageText(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            messageAdapter.addMessage(message);

            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Adapter Class

```
private ArrayList<ChatMessage> messages = new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();
protected Context context;

public MessageAdapter(final String chatUUID, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()...);
}

public void addMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage) {
    messages.add(chatMessage);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public MessageHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    MessageHolder viewHolder = null;
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.messages, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new MessageHolder(layoutView, messages);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MessageHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.messageImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_pacific);
    holder.messageText.setText(messages.get(position).getMessageText());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.messages.size();
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with the firebase code or the adapter, but instead with the LinearLayoutManager.  I believe the code was being added offscreen.  I solved this by changing

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

to

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
```